# How to do a directory wide search for Chinese characters in a text editor?

Tags: character-encoding, sublimetext3, atom-editor, chinese-locale

I have Atom and Sublime and I'm working with a series of documents with some Chinese comments. It seems that both text editor decodes the characters before displaying (happens in a fraction of a second when opening each file where you can see it turn from gibberish into Chinese). After those files are opened, I am able to include them in my directory wide search.

However, without opening any of these documents, I am unable to search at them.

I'm resorting to opening hundreds of tabs currently to work, which is highly inefficient.

I'm guessing both editors are waiting until each file is opened before processing it. How do I ensure that all files in my Project is decoded as Chinese in the background?

I'm opened to using other text editors.